# What changes should I do so that when I enter "a" its says bread and when I enter "b" it says wine?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Here is my code. The formula I entered on my if statement doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int value;

    cout << "a) Bread" << endl;
    cout << "b) Wine" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the letter of the type of product you want to buy: " << endl;
    cin >> value;

    if(value == a){
        cout << "You chose bread";
    } else{
        cout << "You chose wine";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, because you have no variable named `a`. You're trying to compare an `int` with an undefined variable instead of `const char`.

Comment: - a red rectangle shows up at the left of the "if" line
and I think (value == a) is not valid

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo but you need quotes on both sides of a and b

Comment: You have created an *integer* called `value`. How can it be an "a"? Last I checked, "a" was not an integer.

Comment: change the variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    char value; // int => char

    cout << "a) Bread" << endl;
    cout << "b) Wine" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the letter of the type of product you want to buy: " << endl;
    cin >> value;

    if(value == 'a'){ // a => 'a'
        cout << "You chose bread";
    } else{
        cout << "You chose wine";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include some explanation as to what was wrong in the question!

Answer (score 2):

You should always include the error you get with your code, and everything you've tried to solve the problem.

Your error is that if you want to check for `'a'`, then you need to surround it with single quotes. You are trying to compare `value` to a non-existing variable called `a`.

Comment: You also want to change `int value;` to `char value;`.

Comment: oh thanks, single quotes worked. but what if the choices are now three?

Comment: Look into the `switch` and `case` keywords.